# Message boxes not firing on textbox change event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a block of c# code on a TextChanged event for a winform textbox. Several of the voids called have messageboxes attached to them so the operator knows if they have valid data. Unfortunately, these calls get skipped completely. I have called the form in question with show() instead of showdialog() to eliminate the form being modal. Still no soap. The event is triggered by a barcode scanner. Code is as follows:

```
private void txtScanCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string barCode;
    barCode = txtScanCode.Text;

    if (txtScanCode.Text.Length == 12)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Hey, look!", "A message box!", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        FindScanItem(barCode);
        barCode = "";
        txtScanCode.SelectionStart = 0;
        txtScanCode.SelectionLength = txtScanCode.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

I suspect it's a combination of text changed and keypress, but not really sure how it should be triggered properly.

Comment: I'm not a fan of `TextChanged` mostly because it is unreliable.  Have you tried `LostFocus` or something?  So as soon the control focus is lost, it triggers the event.

Comment: Is the TextChanged event getting fired at all? Have you set a breakpoint in it and verified that the condition in the 'if' statement is true?

Comment: @Rufus The TextChanged event does fire. It even executes data functions. It just hates MessageBox.Show().

Comment: No, it doesn't. Your code works fine. Is it perhaps multiline? Also: We don't see a Keypress event! Show us all the relevant code!

Comment: Well, your code works fine for me. Not sure what you mean by the 'data functions'?

Comment: @Rufus - Did you use a barcode scanner? If so, did it add "\r\n"? That might be a clue as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: No, I didn't... if it's somehow possible that more than one character is being added before the `TextChanged` event triggers, then you might try changing your condition to: `if (txtScanCode.Text.Length >= 12)`

Comment: @Tom, where does the `if (txtScanCode.Text.Length == 12)` requirement come from?  Is that the expected length of the string from the barcode scanner?  Is *your* barcode scanner adding "\r\n"?  If so, have you accounted for that your expected string length?  If not, I recommend @RufusL's answer.

Comment: You message box will only fire if `txtScanCode.Text.Length == 12`. This means if the text length is 9 or 14, for example, then no message box on text change. I suspect you are getting different length text values and you are not getting 12 in for your final "time to do work/processing" case that your code is interested in. Set a break point on your `if` statement in your event, and proceed to enter your bar code value as normal. You will then see what your variation is that you are receiving.

Comment: @Tom, my experience with barcode scanners is that they can add end-of-line characters as well as a bunch of garbage control characters that prevent them from showing up in a message box or even text box. Can you step through the code and tell us the value of `txtScanCode.Text` before you bring up the message box?

Comment: Actually, it's not supposed to do anything if the length is not 12. I did check for line returns. Actually, the original code had a trim for that commented out because it never fired.

Comment: why don't you add an int _test = barcode.length after barcode = txtScancode.Text and then add a breakpoint on your if statement, you should be able to see the value of your barcode string and the length of this string in the _test variable?

Comment: A little progress this morning. Paste in a string, and the message boxes fire. Using a bar code scanner, and forget it. Skips right over the message box and goes to the next step. Everything else invoked functions normally (at least until I go to debug that rat's nest - another topic) but the message boxes are ignored.

So is this a barcode issue instead of a textchanged problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week and a half, I have the answer, tested and verified. TaW and BillRuhl were on the right track with Leave and KeyPress. When those did not work, I finally hit on the KeyUp event.

A little background. A generic keyboard wedge USB scanner automatically adds a carriage return that trimming "\r\n" or Environment.Newline() will not get rid of. After several tries using different combinations and keypress, I caught the app firing a form before closing it. The barcode scanner, unlike normal keyboard input or cutting and pasting, continues to send an enter key to anything that listens for it during an event. I know. Buggy. But if we fire on the keyup event instead, like so...

```
private void txtScanCode_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
   {

       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
       {
           e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

           barCode = txtScanCode.Text.Trim().ToString();
           if (!doDataStuff) //This boolean is instantiated as false
           {
               if (txtScanCode.Text.Length == 12)
               {
                   doDataStuff = true; //boolean tells the app go run data functions.
                   MessageBox.Show(this, "Pop up worked!", "Cool!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                   getData(barCode); //Data methods performed on the barcode
                   barCode = "";
                   txtScanCode.Focus();
                   txtScanCode.SelectionStart = 0;
                   txtScanCode.SelectionLength = txtScanCode.Text.Length;
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

...We look only for an enter key, validate on the length of the string (In this case, "==12" is essential for validation), and use KeyEventArgs to filter out Keys.Enter. Works perfectly with one caveat. KeyUp actually works on the form level, so it will fire on other text boxes as well. In this case, txtScanCode is the only one that has data-bound functions behind it, so all the validation is written to check against that control.

Thanks all for chiming in. I think we broke Google a couple of times trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a copy/paste test, and I think the problem may be in your `if` condition. If I copy more than 12 characters and paste it into the text box, the 'if' statement doesn't trigger.

This simple change seemed to fix that case:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length >= 12)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, "Hey, look!", "A message box!",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

    // the rest of your code here
    // (you may want to do some additional validation 
    // on the text if it's more than 12 characters)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different event...I have better luck with the Leave event than I do with the TextChanged event. So your method would look like:

```
private void txtScanCode_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string barCode;
barCode = txtScanCode.Text;

 if (txtScanCode.Text.Length == 12)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(this, "Hey, look!", "A message box!", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

    FindScanItem(barCode);
    barCode = "";
    txtScanCode.SelectionStart = 0;
    txtScanCode.SelectionLength = txtScanCode.Text.Length;
 }
}
```

Don't forget to wire up the Leave event...

Hope that helps
Bill

Comment: this.txtScanCode.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.txtScanCode_Leave);

Comment: That didn't work, but I'll play around with it. TaW mentioned keypress, so I may experiment with that as well.

Comment: @BobRuhl See above. That code works, but not when I scan a barcode. So we may be looking at something else entirely.

Comment: Here is the issue. When I scan into the textbox, the changed event passes a carriage return. I have tried stripping System.Environment.NewLine() and ("\r\n") to no avail. What happens, even on the textbox_Leave event, the system thinks that the enter has been held down. So when a message box fires, this "enter key" fires the OK button before the user can even see it.

It's a keyboard wedge, and programming for a specific scanner is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just put  `MessageBox.Show("ble");` and then `MessageBox.Show("blu);` and the `"blu"` will fire.